# numerical expression has 9 elements: only the first used

Tags: r

I'm a beginner for R I try a simple  R  and did not work properly

```
x <- c(2,3,4,1,3,7,4,9,10)
> x
[1]  2  3  4  1  3  7  4  9 10
> sum(x)
[1] 3
Warning message:
In 1:num : numerical expression has 9 elements: only the first used
```

I didnot know where is the problem

Comment: You've created a function called `sum` accidentally I suspect. Try `rm(sum)` to remove it (assuming you don't need what's stored there any longer) and try again.

Comment: I try it , it works proprely

Comment: this is a great case for using `debugonce`: `debugonce(sum)`; `sum(x)` will bring you inside the evaluating environment of `sum` (as it's defined in your current R session), and you should see something funny going on